# how to open a pop up window every n clicks?

Tags: javascript

How can I open a pop up window in a new tab after clicking a link 'n' times? Where 'n' can be set to any positive whole number.

I'm currently using this code, also found on the site;

```
var sync = true;
window.onbeforeunload = doSync;

function doSync() {
if (sync && !window.sessionStorage.getItem('popupShown')) {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('popupShown', 1);
    window.open('myurl', '_blank');
}
}
```

this opens the pop up only on the first click, once per browser session.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a counter:

```
var sync = true;
window.onbeforeunload = doSync;
var n = 5; // total number of clicks
var current = 1; // current number of clicks

function doSync() {
    if (sync && !window.sessionStorage.getItem('popupShown') && current == n) {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('popupShown', 1);
        window.open('myurl', '_blank');
    }
    else if (sync && !window.sessionStorage.getItem('popupShown') && current < n) {
        current++;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off getting your 'popupShown' variable out of local storage and casting it to an integer before your test, then incrementing it before you set it back to local storage.

Something like this:

```
var sync = true;
var n = 10;
window.onbeforeunload = doSync;

function doSync() {
var popupCount = window.sessionStorage.getItem('popupCount');
if(!popupCount)
  popupCount = 0;

if (sync && popupCount < n) { 
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('popupShown', popupCount++);
    window.open('myurl', '_blank');
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this but it doesn't work. Forgot to tell you that the link is a "random pic" (similar to tumblr's random button) link. Every time it's pressed a new unique pic page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and didactic solution:

You can use a global variable or any better method to store a counter variable.

When the user clicks in your link, a javascript function is called and the counter is incremented.

If the number of clicks is up to open the popup, then do it and set counter = 0 again.

```
i = 0; // There are better ways to implement this counter. This is the simplest way.

function popup()
{
    i++;
    if(i==5)
    {
        alert('PopUp');
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found this solution

```
<script type"text/javascript">
```

function popup() {

if (!sessionStorage.pageCounter){

```
open('http://yahoo.com', '_blank');
sessionStorage.setItem('pageCounter',0);
```

}

else if (sessionStorage.pageCounter == 4){

```
open('http://yahoo.com', '_blank');
```

}

else if (sessionStorage.pageCounter == 9){

```
open('http://yahoo.com', '_blank');
```

}

```
sessionStorage.setItem('pageCounter',parseInt(sessionStorage.pageCounter)+1);
```

}

the popup opens on the first, 5th, and 10th clicks